# eventlistenner scroll with vue js 3 nuxtjs 3 in a component

Tags: typescript, scroll, nuxt.js, vuejs3, pinia

I am currently doing a remote internship with a tutor who is not present. I'm on a project with vue js 3 nuxt js 3 pinia typescript and ionnic. Lots of new stuff for me. My job was to create a component,  a modal and I fulfilled all the objectives except the last one which is a scroll event listener basically when the person scrolls in the modal the links in the menu which corresponds to the section are grayed out but I can't get it to work. If you have any suggestions I'm all ears. At first I tried with scrollspy without success, then I tried another equally ineffective method. Thank you for your response in advance

My code :

```
<!-- eslint-disable vue/no-v-html -->
<template>
  <ion-content class="custom-content">
    <ion-button id="open-modal" color="Light" expand="block">
      <img
        src="../assets/images/wattermark.png"
        alt="button modal integration"
      >
    </ion-button>
    <ion-modal ref="modal" trigger="open-modal">
      <ion-header>
        <span class="w-8" />
        <img src="../assets/images/logoGrincat.svg" alt="log grincat">
        <ion-button class="crossbutton" fill="clear" @click="dismiss">
          <img
            class="cross"
            src="../assets/images/cross-element.png"
            alt="cross"
          >
        </ion-button>
      </ion-header>
      <ul ref="menu" class="contact-menu-links mt-2 mb-2 flex gap-x-1 justify-around">
        <li class="containerLink flex flex-col justify-around items-center p-1">
          <a
            href="#integration"
            :class="{ active: activeSection === 'integration' }"
            class="h-full w-full link flex flex-col justify-around items-center p-1"
            @click="activeSection = 'integration'"
          >
            <span class="w-4 mb-1">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 13 13">
                <path
                  d="M2.4 7.1l3.1 1.7V7.5l-1.8-.9v-.2l1.8-.9V4.2L2.4 5.9v1.2zm8.2 0V5.9L7.5 4.2v1.3l1.8.9v.1l-1.8 1v1.3l3.1-1.7zm1.3-.6c0 3-2.5 5.4-5.4 5.4-2.9 0-5.4-2.4-5.4-5.4s2.5-5.4 5.4-5.4c2.9 0 5.4 2.4 5.4 5.4m1 0c0-3.4-3-6.3-6.4-6.3C3 .2.1 3.1.1 6.5s3 6.3 6.4 6.3c3.5 0 6.4-2.9 6.4-6.3"
                  class="st0"
                  fill="#5a5a69"
                />
              </svg>
            </span>
            <span
              class="link-text flex justify-center items-center leading-none uppercase font-bold text-xs tracking-wider text-center flex-grow"
            >Intégration</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="containerLink flex flex-col justify-around items-center p-1">
          <a
            href="#contact"
            class="link flex flex-col justify-around items-center p-1 h-full w-full"
            @click="activeSection = 'contact'"
          >
            <span class="w-4 mb-1">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 13 13">
                <path
                  d="M3.7 5.3l2.8 1.9 2.8-1.9v3.1H3.7V5.3zM9 4.6L6.5 6.2 4 4.6h5zM2.9 9.3h7.2V3.7H2.9v5.6zm9-2.8c0 3-2.5 5.4-5.4 5.4-2.9 0-5.4-2.4-5.4-5.4s2.5-5.4 5.4-5.4c2.9 0 5.4 2.4 5.4 5.4m1 0c0-3.4-3-6.3-6.4-6.3C3 .2.1 3.1.1 6.5s3 6.3 6.4 6.3c3.5 0 6.4-2.9 6.4-6.3"
                  class="st0"
                />
              </svg>
            </span>
            <span
              class="link-text flex justify-center items-center leading-none uppercase font-bold text-xs tracking-wider text-center flex-grow"
            >Contact</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="containerLink flex flex-col justify-around items-center p-1">
          <a
            href="#information"
            class="link flex flex-col justify-around items-center p-1 h-full w-full"
            @click="activeSection = 'information'"
          >
            <span class="w-4 mb-1">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 13 13">
                <path
                  d="M5.9 3.9h1.3V2.6H5.9v1.3zm0 6.5h1.3V4.7H5.9v5.7zm6-3.9c0 3-2.5 5.4-5.4 5.4-2.9 0-5.4-2.4-5.4-5.4s2.5-5.4 5.4-5.4c2.9 0 5.4 2.4 5.4 5.4m1 0c0-3.4-3-6.3-6.4-6.3C3 .2.1 3.1.1 6.5s3 6.3 6.4 6.3c3.5 0 6.4-2.9 6.4-6.3"
                  class="st0"
                />
              </svg>
            </span>
            <span
              class="link-text flex justify-center items-center leading-none uppercase font-bold text-xs tracking-wider text-center flex-grow"
            >Information</span>
          </a>
        </li>
        <li class="containerLink flex flex-col justify-around items-center p-1">
          <a
            href="#legal-notice"
            class="link flex flex-col justify-around items-center p-1 h-full w-full"
            @click="activeSection = 'legal-notice'"
          >
            <span class="w-4 mb-1">
              <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 13 13">
                <path
                  d="M6.5 11.9c-2.9 0-5.4-2.4-5.4-5.4 0-3 2.5-5.4 5.4-5.4 2.9 0 5.4 2.4 5.4 5.4 0 3-2.5 5.4-5.4 5.4M6.5.2C3 .2.1 3.1.1 6.5s3 6.3 6.4 6.3c3.5 0 6.4-2.9 6.4-6.3S10 .2 6.5.2m.2 3.3c-1.6 0-2.9 1.3-2.9 3s1.3 3 2.9 3C8.1 9.5 9 8.1 9 8.1l-.9-.5s-.7.9-1.5.9c-1.1 0-1.8-.7-1.8-2s.7-2 1.8-2c.8 0 1.4.7 1.4.7l.8-.5s-.7-1.2-2.1-1.2"
                  class="st0"
                />
              </svg>
            </span>
            <span
              class="link-text flex justify-center items-center leading-none uppercase font-bold text-xs tracking-wider text-center flex-grow"
            >Mentions Legales</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ion-content id="containerContentModal">
        <div>
          <!-- // eslint-disable-next-line vue/no-v-html -->
          <section id="integration" @scroll="onSectionScroll('integration')" />
          <section id="contact" @scroll="onSectionScroll('contact')" v-html="application.contactClient" />
          <section id="information" @scroll="onSectionScroll('information')" v-html="application.contactGrincat" />
          <section id="legal-notice" @scroll="onSectionScroll('legal-notice')" v-html="application.rgpd" />
        </div>
      </ion-content>
    </ion-modal>
  </ion-content>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { IonButton, IonModal, IonHeader, IonContent } from '@ionic/vue'
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia'
import { useApplicationStore } from '../stores/application'

const applicationStore = useApplicationStore()
const { application } = storeToRefs(applicationStore)
const activeSection = ref()
function onSectionScroll (section: any) {
  activeSection.value = section
}

function dismiss () {
  modal.value.$el.dismiss()
}

const modal = ref()
const menu = ref()

</script>

<style lang="scss">
ion-content.custom-content {
  --overflow: hidden;
  --padding-bottom: 0;
  height: 30px;
  width: 150px;
  z-index: 900;
  position: absolute;
  top: -10px;
  left: -10px;
}

.contact-menu-links {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  z-index: 999;

  .containerLink {
    color: #5a5a69;
    flex-basis: 25%;
    max-width: 130px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    border-radius: 3px;
    min-width: 75px;
  }

  .containerLink {
    a {
      &:focus {
        background-color: #5a5a69;

        svg {
          path {
            fill: white;
          }
        }
      }

      &:active {
        background-color: #5a5a69;

        svg {
          path {
            fill: white;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  .link-text {
    color: #e20020;
  }
}

ion-modal {
  ion-header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;

    img {
      width: 200px;
    }

    .crossbutton {
      .cross {
        width: 32px;
      }
    }
  }
}

#contact {
  img {
    display: inline-block;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 420px) {
  .contact-menu-links {
    .containerLink span {
      font-size: 0.6rem;
    }
  }
}
</style>
```